# createObject in VB6 does fails when running exe

Tags: vb6, createobject

I have a VB6 program which tries to run a DLL written in C#.
This DLL has a COM interface so I can create an object of a class in it with "CreateObject".
The problem is that it runs and works well when I run it from the VB6 IDE, but when I make an EXE and try to run it, it throws the exception:
"Automation error. The system cannot find the file specified (-2147024894)."

Why is it happening and how can i solve it?

Comment: What OS?  Are you running the IDE elevated vs. the compiled program as a standard user?  Can you show a small procedure where this fails, i.e. some code but not a code snippet missing important details?  Including the declaration of the object reference variable please, so we can see whether you are late-binding or early-binding.

Answer (score 0):

Look at Project, References in the IDE and look which dll or ocx file belongs to the object you are referencing with CreateObject (the Object Manager might also help to find out).
This dll file must be available when the exe is compiled, too. Usually, you need to have it registered with regsvr32.exe.

Answer (score 0):

A technique I use to figure issues of this type is to open the add reference dialog in Visual Basic 6. I scroll the list of available COM Libraries and see if the problem DLL is listed. If it is then  CreateObject should work, you should be able to assign it do a variant variant and use late binding to access it's members.

In addition try temporally set a reference to the variable and instead of using CreateObject use the = New  and see what error messages, if any, it gives you. Generally I found them to be more informative then the ones thrown by CreateObject.

Finally it would help if you post the reason why you are choosing to use CreateObject instead of setting of a reference. If the DLL is a known object that will be continually used by the program then a reference should be set and early binding generally used.

Finally it may be that the error is resulting from a dependency of the C# COM DLL not the DLL itself. If for example I was to take a Com Library and properly register it but it relies on the COM Library Widget2000 and it NOT registered then it will throw the automation error. Especially if you are testing the EXE in it's installed environment and not the environment in which you complied it.

For example suppose I have a CAD program written in VB6 and I have source tree that begins with MyCAD. THe exe is in MyCAD/MainEXE and the shape library is in MyCAD/ShapeLibrary. I run the IDE everything is fine. Then I make my setup and goto my test machine and install it and it error on the creation of shapelibrary.

The first thing I would do it check if MainEXE will run straight out of the MainEXE directory of my source tree. That test will eliminate whether it is a install issue or a quirk of the IDE vs complied version. Then I would look at the setup and see what not being registered. Also look at either the source for the C# library or the setup for the library and see what dependencies it needs. Since it a complied COM DLL you should be able to use a dependency walker tool to see what COM references it needs. Finally make sure the correct version of the .NET framework is installed.

Answer (score 0):

If you are compiling the C# DLL on your test machine - make sure you have ticked the [register for COM Interop setting](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w29wacsy%28v=VS.100%29.aspx). If you are not compiling on the same machine you need to run [RegAsm](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tzat5yw6%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) with the /codebase option.

Answer (score 0):

try compiling it as an installer and include the dll/com that you use in the compilation of the installer package so that the dll/com that you use will be include in the compilation of your exe.., and install it in the windows not just copy past it.